# How to setup java environment in digitalocean?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, digital-ocean

I want to set up java/jsp environment in digitalocean VPS. I need help with that. I found help in digitalocean community but I want to know that which os is best for jsp and tomcat? And also the version of OS. I saw that tomcat is accessible at port 8080 so is there any option that i can access my site at port 80 or something like domain.com/index.jsp instead of domain.com:8080/indes.jsp?

I am still learning java and jsp so for that I need help to set up.

Comment: This question is perhaps better suited for the [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com/), another StackExchange site.

Comment: Oh okay @BasilBourque I will try over there. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat can run on almost any OS, so choose one you are experienced and comfortable with. There's been a tendency to go with CentOS for server deployment, but as far as I'm aware no strong justification for choosing this over Ubuntu. Use whichever version is the most recent released version - for Ubuntu that's 14.04. DigitalOcean provide a variety of images and they're likely to be up to date and well supported.

Tomcat can be setup to run on any port you want, including 80. There are loads of guides to this, here's one that looks comprehensive: http://java-notes.com/index.php/installing-tomcat-with-http-port-80-on-linux